# Why do I cannot create a new Tab from another Form?

Tags: c#

I want to call the NewTab() function from another form. But it doesn't work. I'm new to C# and Programming and need help.

Form1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using CefSharp;
using CefSharp.WinForms;

namespace Browser
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    ChromiumWebBrowser chrome;

    private void Window_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        txtUrl.Text = "https://google.com";
        chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(txtUrl.Text);
        chrome.Parent = tabControl.SelectedTab;
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
        chrome.TitleChanged += Chrome_TitleChanged;
    }

    private void Chrome_AddressChanged(object sender, AddressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            txtUrl.Text = e.Address;
        }));
    }

    private void buttonRefresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
        if (chrome != null)
        {
            chrome.Refresh();
        }
    }

    private void buttonNavigate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
        if(chrome != null)
        {
            chrome.Load(txtUrl.Text);
        }
    }

    private void buttonForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
        if (chrome != null)
        {
            if (chrome.CanGoForward)
            {
                chrome.Forward();
            }
        }
    }

    private void buttonBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
        if (chrome != null)
        {
            if(chrome.CanGoBack)
            {
                chrome.Back();
            }
        }
    }

    private void Window_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Cef.Shutdown();
    }

    public void btnNewTab_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NewTab("https://google.com");
    }

    public void NewTab(string url)
    {
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Text = "New Tab";
        tabControl.Controls.Add(tab);
        tabControl.SelectTab(tabControl.TabCount - 1);
        ChromiumWebBrowser chrome = new ChromiumWebBrowser(url);
        chrome.Parent = tab;
        chrome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        txtUrl.Text = url;
        chrome.AddressChanged += Chrome_AddressChanged;
        chrome.TitleChanged += Chrome_TitleChanged;
    }

    private void Chrome_TitleChanged(object sender, TitleChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
        {
            tabControl.SelectedTab.Text = e.Title;
        }));
    }

    private void closeTabToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl.Controls.Remove(tabControl.SelectedTab);
    }

    private void openMultipleTabsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 form2 = new Form2();
        form2.Show();
    }
}
}
```

Form2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Browser
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.NewTab("https://google.com");
    }
}
}
```

I try to make a Webbrowser with special features. I use CefSharp for this. Sorry for the ugly Code I'm new to C# and Programming. Got most of this from a Youtube tutorial. I'm trying to make another window that you can open with a menustrip that lets you open multiple tabs at once. But for now, I don't even get one new Tab opened. It could be nice if you help me with this.

Comment: Did you try to add `form.Show();` after calling `NewTab`? You create a new instance of Form1 but you don't show it...

Answer (score 2):

You create a new instance of `Form1` but you don't show it.
Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 form = new Form1();
    form.NewTab("https://google.com");
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: @levi_code if that's the case, then you need to set a breakpoint on the constructor and or `NewTab` and step through, this is a different issue. Please create another question with your issue and steps to reproduce. I can almost bet, something hasn't be initialized yet and you're trying to access that object.

Comment: @levi_code: as already written by Çöđěxěŕ, first problem (_nothing happens_) is solved; now you're facing a different problem, but we can't guess what is it without watching at the full code involved

Comment: I have put in the whole Code